# Python customized Exception class should allow to continue the program execution after it has been raised

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

I wrote a Python programm that has a customized Exception class called TAException and it works fine.
But a new requirement forces me to extend its functionaliy. If the user sets a specific flag (-n) on
program startup the program should NOT stop execution if TAException is raised.

Below you see how I tried to implement it. In main() TAException.setNoAbort() gets called if that flag has been set. The rest is maybe self-explaining.
The point is: Obviously it doesn't work. The program always aborts when TAException is raised.
I know why it doesn't work, but I do not know how I can implement it differently. Could you please show me an elegant way to do this?

```
class TAException(Exception):
    _numOfException = 0                                                 # How often has this exception been raised?
    _noAbort = False                                                    # By default we abort the test run if this exception has been raised.

    def __init__(self, TR_Inst, expr, msg):
        '''
        Parameters:
            TR_Inst:    Testreport instance
            expr:       Expression in which the error occured.
            msg:        Explanation for the error.
        '''
        if TR_Inst != None:
            if TAException._noAbort is True:                            # If we abort the test run on the first exception being raised.
                TAException._numOfException += 1                        # Or else only count the exception and continue the test run.
                                                                        # The status of the testreport will be set to "Failed" by TestReportgen.
            else:
                TR_Inst.genreport([expr, msg], False)                   # Generate testreport and exit.

    @staticmethod
    def setNoAbort():
        '''
        Sets TAException._noAbort to True.
        '''
        TAException._noAbort = True
```

Comment: Just to make it explicit: You cannot stop an exception being raised from the exception class itself. You can always instanciate an exception instance (`exc = SomeException()`) without raising it, then later using the variable to raise it anyway: `if somecondition: raise exc`). The exception class is *not informed* of or given an opportunity to cancel the `raise` statement being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the parameter -n your program should not raise the exception but instead use a warning (that won't stop your program). You can find more info on warning here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#module-warnings